# Android Network Service Discovery not firing listener

Tags: android

I've been playing around with Android's Network Service Discovery capabilities recently.  I have everything working, but for some reason I can't get the `NsdManager.RegistrationListener` to ever get called now.

I'm initializing it with a simple callback and then calling `registerService`, but it's not calling `onServiceRegistered` or `onRegistrationFailed`.  The code is below.  I am running this registration inside a service, if that matters.

What I see in the log is "registering service", but never one of the callbacks in the listener.

```
private NsdManager mNsdManager;
private NsdManager.RegistrationListener mRegistrationListener;  

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mNsdManager = (NsdManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().NSD_SERVICE);

    initializeRegistrationListener();
    startAdvertising();
}

public void initializeRegistrationListener() {
    mRegistrationListener = new NsdManager.RegistrationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRegistrationFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {
            Log.i("myapp", "failed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUnregistrationFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceRegistered(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {
            Log.i("myapp", "success");
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceUnregistered(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {

        }
    };
}

public void startAdvertising() {
    NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo  = new NsdServiceInfo();
    serviceInfo.setPort(new ServerSocket(0).getLocalPort());
    serviceInfo.setServiceName("_myapp_one");
    serviceInfo.setServiceType("_http._tcp.");

    Log.i("myapp", "registering service");
    mNsdManager.registerService(serviceInfo, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, mRegistrationListener);
}
```

Comment: I am facing a similar issue , but for my code I dont necessarily need to restart or uninstall the app. I keep retrying and after few runs the service registration succeeds(Don't know the real cause behind this and how to fix it). My guess is that possibly the android OS is not throwing a timeout exception in the scenario when service is taking an indefinite amount of time to register. That is why i neither get an error in onRegistrationFailed nor the onServiceRegistered is getting invoked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The callbacks onServiceRegistered or onRegistrationFailed never occurred. In my case I solved it by uninstalling my app and rebooting the mobile phones I was using.

Android changes the service name in order to resolve a conflict, so that's why we need to update the name that we initially requested with the name Android actually used. I run the application so many times that could it be that Android may have ran out of service names?